# Inkscape 0.92 - How to Get SVG Path Coordinates?

Tags: svg, coordinates, inkscape, coordinate-transformation

Inkscape saves paths as relative instead of absolute, hence:

```
0, 0, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100
```

becomes:

```
M -0.06681738,270.60714 H 26.5265 V 297 H 0 Z
```

Apparently, in previous versions of Inkscape (0.4), it was possible to change this by switching Path data value from Relative to Absolute, however, this no longer works.

There was also a Java-based converter, which I was unable to run.

I would write my own converter in Python, if I knew what these values meant.

Edit whole code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg8"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 26.458333 26.458334"
   height="100"
   width="100">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />

  <g
     transform="translate(0,-270.60714)"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       id="path815"
       d="M -0.06681738,270.60714 H 26.5265 V 297 H 0 Z"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: These _are_ absolute coordinates. H means horizontal (repeat the last y coordinate and take the given value as x coordinate), V means vertical (repeat the last x coordinate and take the given value as y coordinate). Spec for path commands is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathData).

Comment: Those two paths aren't the same. The first is a square, the second is a triangle. It also has a horizontal movement of 0, which is redundant, so something strange is happening.

Comment: @Peter At least it's displayed as a square; I added whole code to the question.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot they are absolute coordinates. So the square start at (~0, 270.6), goes horizontally to (26.5, 270.6), vertically to (26.5, 279), and then back to the start. Then the whole thing is translated 270.6 units up, so it starts at (0,0), or thereabouts.